# Save number to a variable within a loop JAVA

Tags: java, loops, variables

My program takes a number of grades(from a notepad file), and then that many grade percentages, and saves them to letter grades. I then print out how many A's, B's, etc. I also need to find the highest and lowest grades.

What I want to do is at the end of my grade checking loop, save the current grade to a variable so I can compare all the variables later to see which is the highest and lowest. The issue is, I don't know how many grades will be input, so I will need an infinite possibility of variables. Here is the relevant section of code:

```
  while (scores > 0 && in.hasNextInt()) {
     int grade = in.nextInt();

     if (grade >= 90) {
        A++;
     } else if (grade >= 80) {
        B++;
     } else if (grade >= 70) {
        C++;
     } else if (grade >= 60) {
        D++;
     } else {
        F++;
     }
     scores--;
     scoreTotals = (scoreTotals + grade);
  }
```

I want to do something like this:

```
    int variableCount = 1;
    int grade(variableCount) = grade;
    variableCount++;
```

And then go on to compare the variables my loop made to determine the lowest and highest.

I've looked up definine a variable by using a variable, but I'm not finding anything. Am I going down the right path here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you make two variables that store the highest and lowest, and as you are going through this loop, update them if you find a new bigger or smaller one.

Try:

```
int highest = 0;
int lowest = 100;
while (scores > 0 && in.hasNextInt()) {
 int grade = in.nextInt();

 if (grade >= 90) {
    A++;
 } else if (grade >= 80) {
    B++;
 } else if (grade >= 70) {
    C++;
 } else if (grade >= 60) {
    D++;
 } else {
    F++;
 }

 if (grade > highest) {
    highest = grade;
 }
 if (grade < lowest) {
    lowest = grade;
 }
 scores--;
 scoreTotals = (scoreTotals + grade);
}
```

Comment: That idea is so much more simple than mine....Thank you! I'm still curious though, was my proposed idea even possible? Can you define varibles within a loop using other variables?

Comment: be aware of scope. anything you define inside a set of braces, in a loop, etc will be gone by the time you leave them. things have to be defined beforehand to last through it.

you can define variables in a loop though. just be aware they start all over after each iteration.

(someone correct me if i'm wrong - i know some languages deviate)

Comment: if your idea was to loop again after this loop, and find the min and max then , yes, you could. however, that's a waste of time looping an additional time (less efficient).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make this too complicated.

```
int highest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

while (...)
{
    // your existing stuff...

    highest = Math.max(highest, grade);
    lowest = Math.min(lowest, grade);
}
```

At the end, `highest` and `lowest` will be the highest and lowest grades.

Comment: We haven't learned about the math method in class yet, so unfortunately, I can't use it. Thank you though!